# Unsubscribe from event listener react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, event-listener, react-router-dom

In a class-based react component you could simply do;

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener('resize', this.resizeHandler);
}
```

Although I am unsure how to do this in a Function Based Component with React Hooks?

In my application, I perform the function below on a button click in a Component `LoginCard`.

```
const handleLogin = (email, password) => {
  loginService.login(email, password)
    .then((response) => {
      if (!response.error) {
        props.history.push("/");
      }
    });
}
```

And I wrap the export of `LoginCard` in a `withRouter` function from `react-router-dom` to redirect to the route address.

`export default withRouter(LoginCard);`

Inside the `LoginCard` Component I have a `Tabs` Component which has the event listener in the `useEffect` hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
      setUnderLineStyle(getUnderlineStyle());
      window.addEventListener("resize", _.throttle(() => { 
         setUnderLineStyle(getUnderlineStyle())}, 
         300), 
         {passive:true});
   }, [props]);
```

However, when I click that button in `LoginCard` and get redirected to `/` and then resize the window, the function inside the resize event lister `setUnderLineStyle(getUnderlineStyle())` gets called.

I have tried to add the following in `useEffect` but `setUnderLineStyle(getUnderlineStyle())` still gets called on resize.

```
return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", _.throttle(() => { 
                setUnderLineStyle(getUnderlineStyle())}, 
                300), 
                {passive:true});
```

Any ideas? Even around a better redirect method to get to `/` via `react-router-dom` or how to effectively unsubscribe from event listeners?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Make a second `useEffect` solely for the use of unmounting. Empty dependencies in `useEffect` make it effectively function as a `componentDidMount`, and the return of that effectively functions as a `componentWillUnmount`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Do mounting stuff here

    return () => {
        // Do unmounting stuff here
    };
}, []);
```

Comment: I think in your answer your are missing callback to useEffect( () => {}, []);